# Is it possible to use static final variables for Spring Expression Language?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I'm using CaffeineCache in my SpringBoot application, and here is one of my annotations for a method:

```
@Cacheable(value = PROMOCODE_BY_CONFIG_BUNDLE_CODE, key = "{#configBundleCode, #siebelId ?: 'all'}")
    public Long countPromocodesByConfigBundleCodeAndSiebelId(String configBundleCode, String siebelId) {
        return preferentialMapper.countPromocodesByConfigBundleCodeAndSiebelId(configBundleCode, siebelId, NULL_SIEBEL_PROMOCODE_CACHE_KEY);
    }
```

I have this variable:

```
private static final String NULL_SIEBEL_PROMOCODE_CACHE_KEY = "all";
```

and I want to use it in my SpEL query instead of 'all'. I've tried to use it with `#` or `$` symbols, but that doesn't work.

Is it possible to use the variable in the query, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a `type operator`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types

So, you can do like this:

```
T(com.my.proj.ClassWithConstant).NULL_SIEBEL_PROMOCODE_CACHE_KEY
```

But your `NULL_SIEBEL_PROMOCODE_CACHE_KEY` has to be `public`.